# Prestashop 1.6 make left column for any pages after copy the default theme is not working?

Tags: templates, themes, prestashop-1.6

I wanted to create a theme in Prestashop 1.6. So to do that I just copied Prestashop 1.6 default theme and renamed it as custom-theme. From backend I made custom-theme activeted. As per my design I wanted to make left column for the home page. So to that I made index to left column from backend APPEARANCE OF COLUMNS settings but I did not see any changes. But if I don't make any copy of the deafult theme and make change the left column in index page then the left column is coming without any problem. So can someone kindly tell me whats the issue here when I make the copy of default theme and made the left column settings for index or any other pages it is not coming? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is doing a reset(down arrow menu, just above delete) of the module I wanted to display on the left column eg. Categories block

Answer (score 0):

The columns are activated by backend:
Preferences->themes->advanced options 
and there "aspect columns"
active in "index"